contribution form error with Stripe webhook error
We are using a contribution form (component) on https://pulsevoices.org/energize-pulse-test-2024/. It is connected to stripe payment gateway. Sometimes this form gets submitted successfully and sometimes getting error. When it failed then this error is received "It failed due to error. Sorry an error occurred and your request was not completed. (Error ID: jIVa-YeFh-jAIY)" Screenshot : https://prnt.sc/l0NIZZABJ2nq
We have tried several tasks to resolve this.

Reconfigured the Stripe webhooks and tested them at this link (get a green bar indicating success): https://pulsevoices.org/civicrm/stripe/fix-webhook/
cleared civi cache
clean URLs enabled
updated webhook API secret key and signing secret

In the CiviCRM > Administer > Administration Console > View Log page, I see these errors:
3314    2024-05-15 10:38:12-0400    [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
3275    2024-05-15 10:38:12-0400    [error]
3261    2024-05-15 10:38:06-0400    [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
3222    2024-05-15 10:38:06-0400    [error]
3220    2024-05-15 09:56:08-0400    [error] Stripe(17): webhook signature validation error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload
3218    2024-05-15 09:55:44-0400    [error] Stripe(17): webhook signature validation error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload
3204    2024-05-15 09:54:38-0400    [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
3158    2024-05-15 09:54:38-0400    [error]
3131    2024-05-15 09:37:29-0400    [debug] AJAX Error ({error_id}): failed with exception
3129    2024-05-15 09:34:56-0400    [info] Contribution 4053 Receipt sent
3127    2024-05-15 09:34:55-0400    [error] Stripe(17): webhook signature validation error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload
3125    2024-05-15 09:34:54-0400    [info] Contribution 4053 updated successfully
3123    2024-05-15 09:34:51-0400    [error] Stripe(17): webhook signature validation error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload 

In the ConfigandLog error logs, these are the errors:
2024-05-15 09:37:29-0400  [debug] AJAX Error ({error_id}): failed with exception
Array
(
    [error_id] => jIVa-YeFh-jAIY
    [exception] => CRM_Core_Exception: "Bad Request"
#0 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(72): Civi\Api4\Action\StripePaymentintent\ProcessPublic->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#1 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(156): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\StripePaymentintent\ProcessPublic))
#2 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(256): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\StripePaymentintent\ProcessPublic))
#3 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(91): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#4 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Api4/Page/AJAX.php(116): civicrm_api4("StripePaymentintent", "ProcessPublic", (Array:9), NULL)
#5 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Api4/Page/AJAX.php(55): CRM_Api4_Page_AJAX->execute("StripePaymentintent", "ProcessPublic", (Array:9), NULL)
#6 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(322): CRM_Api4_Page_AJAX->run((Array:5), NULL)
#7 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:16))
#8 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:5))
#9 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:5))
#10 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke(Object(WP))
#11 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))
#12 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#13 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(830): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#14 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1336): WP->main("")
#15 /home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#16 /home/pulsev5/public_html/index.php(17): require("/home/pulsev5/public_html/wp-blog-header.php")
#17 {main}

)


I'd be most grateful if someone could advise on what and how to resolve this issue. We've been working on for some time but nothing seems to work. Please and thank you!

I would suggest to check civicrm_firewall table and delete all the rows with your IP address.

Hi @pradeep-nayak,
Appreciate your quick response!
there are no blocked IPs in civi firewall. But also this isn't happening just for me. In fact sometimes my tests are successful however, real donor submissions are failing.
Linked below is the civi firewall settings. Any other suggestions for how to fix this issue?
https://prnt.sc/dL0tOn7PYpl9
